# Using Maven, how to properly deploy WAR depending on J2EE/JPA JAR?

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, war

I'm creating a modular Maven project. Project is deployed on Glassfish 3.1.  Project (webapp) consists of three modules:

- "Common", consisting of core functionality (persistence, authentication logic, etc.), built into a JAR
- "User", depending on Common, built into a WAR
- "Admin", also depending on Common and WARred

Both WAR use heavy annotated (@Entity, @Inject, @EJB, ...) classes from Common. Currently Common is a JAR, but it's not a requirement. The question is: *How to properly deploy such project?*

By my current (google and stackoverflow influenced) knowledge:

- Common cannot be a JAR, because .jar file is put into WEB-INF\lib directory inside JAR. This makes deploy-time initialization, because Glassfish expects .classes and produces an "Unsatisfied dependencies" error, resulting in failed deployment.
- Common cannot be a WAR, because with WAR overlay copying ocurrs after build -- resulting in build depending on itself...

**EDIT**

As Mike Decks comment suggests setup is ok, I assume supplying a full error message would be useful:

```
Deployment Error for module: User: Error occurred during deployment: 
Exception while loading the app : WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies 
for type [Authentication] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point
[[field] @Inject xxx.xxx.servlets.LoginFilter.authentication].
```

What would that mean? *What could be the cause?*

**EDIT2**

I'm enclosing relevant classes (trimmed a bit, i.e. not get/set methods, imports, etc.)

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Inject
    Authentication authentication;

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        LoginBean login = (LoginBean) httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("loginBean");
        if((login == null || !login.isAuthenticated())) {
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            String requestUrl = httpRequest.getRequestURI().toString();
            authentication.setNavigateAfterLogin(requestUrl);
            httpResponse.sendRedirect("./../login.html");
        }       
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

and:

```
@SessionScoped  
public class Authentication implements Serializable {   
    @Inject
    private UserDatabaseController userDb;
    private ShopUser user;
    private String navigateAfterLogin;
    private String login;
    private String password;

    public boolean doLogin(String username, String password) {
        List<ShopUser> users = userDb.getUsers();
        for(ShopUser shopUser : users) {
            if(shopUser.getLogin().equals(username) && shopUser.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                setUser(shopUser);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void doLogout() {
        setUser(null);
    }   

    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return getUser() != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Common can and should be a JAR.  I'm not sure why your deployment is failing, but WEB-INF/lib is absolutely intended to house JAR file dependencies of the WAR.  It sounds like you've got the right basic setup, what you really need to do is troubleshoot the deployment error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was solved by adding *empty* `META-INF/beans.xml` and `META-INF/faces-config.xml`. Empty files imply default configuration, among other things letting Glassfish know that it should look for classes needed for @Inject, while lack of them does not.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it seems that this is a problem with CDI. It is unable to find a proper implementation for type 'Authentication' when it attempts to initialize your LoginFilter. Check whether the implementation class of type 'Authentication' is available in your JAR file.

Like @Mike has mentioned, you are supposed to put your dependencies into your lib folder as JAR files, so that should not be a issue. I guess this is not a problem with Maven.

Comment: Type 'Authentication' is present inside JAR. Perhaps the fact that it is @Injected has something to do with the error? What could be the cause and/or how to fix this?

Comment: What is 'Authentication'  (ex. An EJB) ? Is it something that is injectable by the container ?

Comment: Authentication is a @SessionScoped (javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped) managed bean injected into LoginFilter class (@Inject).

Comment: Then it is definitely eligible to be injected by container. Can you put up the source of your Authentication class and the LoginFilter class so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: Added relevant parts of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use an EAR to package EJB-jars and WARs.

Comment: one of the advances in Java EE 6 is 'simplified packaging' which allows developers to integrate EJB's directly into WAR files as classes (WEB-INF/classes) or libraries (WEB-INF/lib).  Creating an ear to resolve this may be a work-around, but it should be the last thing done... because it may not resolve this situation anyway.