# Commons Jars, pack or not?

Tags: java, maven, jar, war

the closest I found was this topic: [Using Maven, how to properly deploy WAR depending on J2EE/JPA JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158148/using-maven-how-to-properly-deploy-war-depending-on-j2ee-jpa-jar), but it doesn't answer the question.

Nowadays I am working in a project with 5 web components and they all use a "core" jar, with the entities, enum. The common stuff.

Currently we pack the "core" jar inside of each component war. The downside is that you need to generate all components when the core has changed. In order to avoid Serialization and  Marshalling problems.

One solution  I thought is to generate the war solo and put all it's dependencies into a lib folder. The downside of this is forget to add a certain dependecy.

Do you know any other way to deal with this situation?

Comment: I don't get it. If you have a CI environment, and are using Maven, then simply committing a change to the core will cause your CI to recompile (and hopefully test) all dependent modules. Doing this manually is senseless and error prone.

Comment: Why on earth do a manual task that maven and automated builds do for you already?

Comment: "The downside is that you need to generate all components when the core has changed" - you mean update dependent artifacts when they have been updated against the new core jar.

Answer (score 0):

ideal solution is to configure maven war plugin to pull up all dependencies for that war project and put it inside `WEB-INF/lib` while building war

this way you won't have to manually remember all the jar, it will pull up all from dependencies

Comment: I think this question is about rebuilding all the war files when the core changes - rather than including the core dependency. CI provides the answer to that question...

Comment: in that case CI build should take care updating all dependencies by building (if required) and installing in local cache and let war plugin pick up fresh dependencies

Comment: Yes, the question is like @BoristheSpider said the question is about rebuilding all the war files when the core changes. I'll Look for CI.

Comment: just set up a build server that listens to changes you made in your project or its components and rebuilds it