# How do I package/deploy entity library on GlassFish 4.1

Tags: java, maven, jpa, glassfish

I'm quite new to JavaEE, and I need to understand how to structure an application made up of several projects.

I have the following projects, which I wish to deploy to a(or several) GlassFish servers:

- entity/jar - Java lib for JPA entity classes
- entity-manager-client/jar - Remote interfaces for entity managers
- entity-manager/ejb/jar - Entity managers (EJB) and Local interfaces
- www/war - JSF web application (uses entity/entity-manager-client)
- myapp/war - JSF web application (uses entity/entity-manager-client)

My question is this - how do I bundle these correctly - separate web projects each using remote interfaces, EJBs for entity management, and JPA entities.

I'm using the Maven Shade plugin to bundle the entity and entity-manager-client projects with the entity-manager, but this seems like a terrible idea, as now it seems like I have to also do the same for the web projects.

Comment: Does this provide some insight? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158148/using-maven-how-to-properly-deploy-war-depending-on-j2ee-jpa-jar?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @EngineerDollery. Sort of - there was a further gap in my understanding that I've worked out. I assumed that the entity classes were scoped as per the packaging (normal POJO) - it seems that if the Entity is packaged in the EJB/jar, I don't need to package the Entities separately into the war archive, only use the Maven "provided" scope for my IDE and allow the container (GlassFish) to manage the rest. After this, the relationship and packaging makes more sense.

Comment: You should write up an answer to your question then, and mark it as accepted. That way others may benefit from your learning.

Comment: Just restructuring the application to prove it works (have only proved it with Local EJB implementations so far), then I certainly will :) Cheers!